# Get the center of the screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to get the center of the screen when I initialize a class.
I have gotten that using CustomPainter like this:

```
class Pinter extends CustomPainter {

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

  final Offset center = size.center(Offset.zero);
```

But I just can get the center when I call that class, I would like to get the center of the screen when a variable is initialized.

How i can get it?

Comment: What about `MediaQuery.of(context).size` and then use `width/2` and `height/2`?

Comment: Thank you  Günter, I am going to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `MediaQuery` object for that:

```dart
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
final center = Offset(size.width/2, size.height/2);
```

Look [at the documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/size.html).